# Need help on integrating .Net based application with Kofax device

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ocr, kofax

I am looking for some help documents which explains the steps to integrate .Net based applications with Kofax devices. I have visited KOfax official site and found that such help documents are available but not accessible for anonymous users. It is only accessible to Customers or business Partners. At this moment, I do not comply this both conditions. Can anyone please guide me with the process needed for integration and provide me any help link which explains the things ? Any information related to using Kofax Capture Document Access API in a .net application will be very helpful. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Developer's Guide and API Reference Guide are both available public on the product support site: [Kofax Capture 10.1 Documentation](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Capture/00_Product_Documentation__User_Guides/00_Kofax_Capture_Product_Documentation_Master/02_Kofax_Capture_101_Product_Documentation/01_All_Kofax_Capture_101_Product_Documentation_compressed) (updated link, but now requires login).  That page also links to prior versions of Kofax Capture if that is what you need.

From the Developer's Guide, this sounds like the topic for which you are looking:

> Kofax Capture Document Access .NET Type Implementation makes it possible for the custom module to access batch information from Kofax Capture. This library also allows your custom module to relay batch information from the custom module to Kofax Capture.

*update:*
If you are looking for a sample for developing a custom module, the product comes with several samples installed to `CaptureSV\Source\Sample Projects\CustMod.`  There is also an older sample available here: [KC8 Color To Bitonal Image Converter Module](ftp://ftp.kofax.com/pub/support/capture/obsolete/kc/8/utility_sample_sdk_releases/col2bitonalconverter.zip)*.  Though the installer does not recognize later versions of Kofax Capture, the include source is a useful example.

**C# vs VB.NET**

I believe all of the official product documentation and official samples use VB.NET.  If you have any trouble with the differences you should be able to use a [code coverter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert snippets to C#.  In contrast to the *product* documentation, ["Application Notes"](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Capture/00_Product_Documentation__User_Guides/00_Kofax_Capture_Product_Documentation_Master/02_Kofax_Capture_101_Product_Documentation/02_Kofax_Capture_101_Related_Application_Note_Documents) (updated link, but now requires login) are written by Technical Support, and often contain C# samples, such as ["Sample Workflow Agents"](ftp://ftp.kofax.com/pub/support/capture/kc/10.1/product_documentation/application_notes/appnote-sample_workflow_agents.pdf)* which are all in C#.  Application Notes from prior versions of Kofax Capture are often still relevant to the current version.

*These links appear to now prompt for credentials but then still download if credential prompt is canceled.

Comment: Thanks Stephen....this is exactly what I was looking for. But one problem the code that is provided in the developer's guide is in visual basic... Do we have a developer guide which covers the code in C# ?

Comment: Official docs and samples are all in VB.NET, but see updated answer for suggestions.

Comment: Definitely recommend the C# route. We have a Kofax Export Connector and several Scan Panels plus a "Custom Panel" all in C# that are working great. Currently running Kofax 10.1 and building in Visual Studio 2015 and building deployment MSI packages for them using InstallShield Express LE 2017.  InstallShield handles the COM part of the deployment nicely. Also I highly recommend setting up interactive debugging for your code in Visual Studio; we have it set up for our export connectors. I found some older Kofax docs that mostly work, with appropriate updates, and show the approach.